# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_own_batch'

Tags: python, pyglet

```
import pyglet

window =  pyglet.window.Window()

label = pyglet.text.Label.draw("Hello world application")

@window.event
def on_draw():
  window.clear()
  label.draw()




pyglet.app.run()
```

the error:

```
2021-10-19 13:39:19.070 Python[87264:4558537] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be writ
ten to /var/folders/m9/g3kwd6vn1cx4n7v76ttysp8m0000gn/T/org.python.python.savedState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damanbirsingh/Desktop/alarm.py", line 5, in <module>
    label = pyglet.text.Label.draw("Hello world application")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyglet/text/layout.py", line 1209, in draw
    if self._own_batch:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_own_batch'
```

Comment: Please, don't abuse tags. I will remove the unnecessary tags.

Comment: seems like you've made a mistake there. Check out this example: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/text.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some error in your code try below code

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

For more info visit https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it is really helpful for me.